# Live Video SDK for Android devices

Tags: android

Is there an SDK for sharing live video between android devices?  for example like skypekit but I think skypekit is not yet supporting mobile devices just desktop.

Comment: "SkypeKit is a collection of software and APIs that allows Internet-connected devices or applications to offer Skype voice and video calls. It's designed to work with a wide variety of chip sets, operating systems, and audio/video devices." I think Skype kit could be worth a try

Comment: my droid X2 comes with a skype app, so I'm pretty sure it can be done.

Comment: come on guys! I'm the only guy who wants live video?

Answer (score 3):

SkypeKit supports video on embeededd devices and on desktops. Developing any mobile device (mobile or tablet) running iOS or Android is currently prohibited in the licence terms.

We do not currently offer any APIs or SDKs that would support this use case at this time.